# jquery touchmove event and very large content

Tags: image, mobile, touch-event

I have very large conten (a lot of pictures). I want to use css3 transition transform.
I bind to touchmove event, and calculate new x position.

But I have issue: the position by x does not change smoothly on mobile (on desctop all ok).
Event Touch comes with delays.

I try hidde don't used content (vissability: hidden) its not help.

Answer (score 1):

Try throttling how fast the event handler makes the changes.  It's counter intuitive, but by slowing things down, you will make them appear faster.  The touchmove events are firing incredibly fast, far faster than the refresh rate of the screen.

Ideally, you would use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) to do that.

Or if that is too experimental for your taste, simply make sure you are not performing your event handler actions faster than 60 frames per second (1 event handler action every 1000/60 milliseconds, the screen's refresh rate).  If you still have problems at 1000/60 milliseconds, try a slower rate.  The frame rate of video is 30 frames per second.  Something between 30 and 60 frames should look good.

So that looks like this:

```
var lastFrameTime;
var myTouchMoveHandler = function (e) {
    var now = Date.now();
    if (now < lastFrameTime + 1000/60) {
        return;
    }
    // your event handler code afterward
    // ...
    // then update the lastFrameTime 
    lastFrameTime = now;
}
```